# The '*' symbol automatically starts typing repeatedly everytime in linux. (Ubuntu18.04)

Tags: keyboard, touchpad, cursor, flicker

My ubuntu18.04 Dell Vostro3546 is facing many problems relating to cursor jumping, repeated key typing and on-boot screen flickering. Please help me, I've been stuck for days and my work is on halt.

1. cursor-jumping : cursor jumps to start of line while typing and keep moving there, until I press ESC. Also, while reading pdf and on browsers the window automatically scrolls to the top. And it is not the because of touching the touchpad while typing.
2. repeated-key typing : When I type letters like 'c','z','v', etc it keepps typing '*'. Eg. c*****atc**h. Also, mouse/touchpad stops working after that.
3. Flickering on-boot : While booting, when screen shows ubuntu, the screen keeps flickering. And before the login window, it displays black screen with many system informations like mounting,GNOME, etc written in white.

Comment: Most likely a hardware issue. One user posted his issue was corner of a book on keyboard. Your may just need a good cleaning or you may need full replacement. If laptop can you try an external keyboard?

Comment: Try connecting an external monitor/lcd with an external keyboard, that might allow you to continue your work. This does seems like a hardware problem if your laptop was working before. Have you done anything to the laptop lately? New installation, hardware modification, etc.